# FormGroupDirective submitted value doesn't change when programmatically submitting a form

Tags: angular

I'm trying to programmatically submit a form and check the submitted status of a formgroupdirective but it is always set to false. How can I trigger it to set to true?

TS:

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control && control.invalid);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isShowErrors: boolean = false;
  sampleForm: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('testForm') testForm: NgForm;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private el: ElementRef){}

  ngOnInit(){
   this.sampleForm = this.fb.group({
     name: ['', Validators.required]
   });
  }

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

  submit(){
    this.isShowErrors = true;
    console.log(this.testForm);
    if(this.sampleForm.valid){
      //navigate
    }
  }

  buttonClick(){
    this.testForm.ngSubmit.emit();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="sampleForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" #testForm="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!sampleForm.valid && isShowErrors">This field is invalid</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
<button type="button" (click)="buttonClick()">Submit</button>
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1r2mbv)

Answer (score 0):

Upon giving the form an `id` and the same name to the `form` attribute of the button, removing the `(click)` event on the button and changing `type` to submit, I was able to trigger the submitted value to true.

The HTML now looks like this:

```
<form id="sampleForm" [formGroup]="sampleForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" #testForm="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!sampleForm.valid && isShowErrors">This field is invalid</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
<button type="submit" form="sampleForm">Submit</button>
```

However, I would still like to see if it can be done with a click event and the type as button.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. No solution to make submitted status of a formgroupdirective `true`  on `(click)` yet?